# Magento 2: showing error when running command setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I am getting this error when running setup:di:compile command, Plese help this is the error in SSH showing

```
    Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 22 secs 218.0 MiB

  [ReflectionException]                                     
  Class Magento\GiftCardAccount\Helper\Data does not exist  



  [ReflectionException]                                     
  Class Magento\GiftCardAccount\Helper\Data does not exist  


setup:di:compile
```

I also run this command to no more about issue setup:di:compile -vvv

and it is showing

> Exception trace:
>    () at /data/websites/devtbl2.wddemo.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:37
>    Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() at /data/websites/devtbl2.wddemo.net/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassReaderDecorator.php:35
>    Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassReaderDecorator->getConstructor() at /data/websites/devtbl2.wddemo.net/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Area.php:53
>    Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Area->getList() at /data/websites/devtbl2.wddemo.net/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:109
>    Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->getDefinitionsCollection() at /data/websites/devtbl2.wddemo.net/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:84

Answer (score 0):

Please check module `GiftcardAccount` with Helper `Data.php` class exist or not.

If not please check from which file above class is calling. Remove those class from file if Data.php file not exist at above file,

or

If Data.php file exist check __construct() function with dependency of class.

Thanks.